# number ranges redistribution based on query results

Tags: mysql, algorithm, math

I need to find a ways redistribute the number ranges when parallel exporting from MySQL:

[image]

Example output (SQL queries results):

[image]

what is the best way to redistribute the number ranges after getting the initial results, so the results will be more evenly distributed?

(estimated) desired output:

[image]

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about. I wonder if this question would be better directed towards the dba forum

Comment: @Strawberry I know its a bit confusing but the question is algorithmic in nature...how to re-distribute the number ranges based on the results column...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that originally you believe your data is uniformly distributed, and now you have a view of the amount of entries at every evenly spaced bin. You can now update your belief about the distribution of your data: within every bin, the data is uniformly distributed, but bins with a higher result have a larger concentration.

Your updated distribution will tell you that you believe the number of results  q to be equal to the sum of all the results in the buckets where the max bound is below q, plus

`(q-min(q))/(max(q)-min(q))*size(q)+`

where `min(q)` and `max(q)` give you the max and min bounds of the bucket that q belongs to, and `size(q)` is the amount of results in the bucket that `q` belongs to. This is a piecewise linear function where the slope at bucket i is its relative size to the total. Now divide by the total number of results to get a probability distribution. To get the places where you should query, find the ten values of x where this piecewise function is equal to .1,.2,.3.... 1.0 . This is a lot easier than inverting an arbitrary function if you exploit the piecewise linear property , for example if you are trying to find the x associated to .2, first find the bucket i such that `min(.2)=lower_bnd_bucket(i)/total<=.2<=upper_bnd_bucket(i)=max(.2)`, This gives you `min(.2)`, `max(.2)` and `size(.2)`.
 Then you just have to invert the linear function associated to that bucket

```
x=(.2-sum_of_buckets_lessthan_i)*(max(.2)-min(.2))/size(.2)+min(.2)
```

Note that size should not be 0 since your are dividing by it, which makes sense (if the bucket is 0, you should skip it). Finally, if you want the places you are querying to be integers, you can round the values using your preferred criteria. What we are doing here is updating with Bayes our belief of where the 10 deciles will be, based on observations
on the distribution in the 10 places you already queried. You can refine this further once you see the result of this query, and you will eventually reach convergence.

For the example on your table, to find the updated  upper limit of bucket 1 , you check that 
 2569/264118<0.1 (first ten percent),
then you check that
 that (2569+14023)/264118<0.1

and finally you check that ((2569+14023+123762)/264118)>0.1

so your new estimate for the decile should be  in between 1014640 and 1141470. 
Your new estimate for the upper theshold of the first bucket is

decile_1=(.1-(2569+14023)/264118)*(1141470-1014640)/(123762/264118)+1014640=1024703

similarly, your estimate for the upper bound for the second bucket is:
(.2-(2569+14023)/264118)*(1141470-1014640)/(123762/264118)+1014640=1051770. Note that this linear interpolation will work until the update for the upper limit of bucket 6, since ((2569+14023+123762)/264118)<.6 and you will now need to use the limits for the old bucket ten when updating the buckets 6 and higher.

Comment: is it possible for you to give a practical example? I find your answer a bit confusing ...

Comment: I have added an example. The whole thing is similar in flavor to bisection, where you use the information of previous candidate bounds to generate new candidate bounds.